# How to extract hour, day of the week from categorical data?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, time-series

I have data like this (it's a time series problem):

```
Time                    y
2017-01-01 00:00:00   34002
2017-01-01 01:00:00   37947
2017-01-01 02:00:00   41517
2017-01-01 03:00:00   44476
2017-01-01 04:00:00   46234
```

I want to extract the hour, day of the week and day off as categorical variables, but somehow it doesn't work:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(dataset)
data.columns = ["y"]

data.index = pd.to_datetime(data)
data["hour"] = data.index.hour
data["weekday"] = data.index.weekday
data['is_weekend'] = data.weekday.isin([5,6])*1

data.head()
```

**Python throws the following error, with which I don't know what to do:**

```
 2 data.columns = ["y"]
      3 
----> 4 data.index = pd.to_datetime(data)
      5 data["hour"] = data.index.hour
      6 data["weekday"] = data.index.weekday

ValueError: to assemble mappings requires at least that [year, month, day] be specified: [day,month,year] is missing
```

Comment: `data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elaborating on the answer included in @MrFruppes comment:

The problem here is that we were trying to convert the DataFrame data to `datetime` objects, rather than convert the index of the DataFrame to `datetime` objects.

It is possible to access a DataFrame's index using the `.index` property.
Feeding those values into the `.to_datetime()` method and assigning the outputs to the `data.index` allows us to overwrite the original values with new values that have been converted to `datetime` objects.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame(dataset)
data.columns = ['y']
```

Here, we access the `.index` and convert it.

```
data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index)
data["hour"] = data.index.hour
data["weekday"] = data.index.weekday
data['is_weekend'] = data.weekday.isin([5,6])*1

data.head()
```